# ConstraintViolationException with CascadeType from Hibernate package

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, foreign-keys

The application is using Hibernate 3 and I've been reading some issues with JPA annotations vs Hibernate annotations. See [Cascade common mistakes](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/cascade-jpa-hibernate-annotation-common-mistake/).

I'm working with a legacy code so the entities are a total mess.

Previously my entity was:

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", targetEntity = Investiment.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL,
            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN,
            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.PERSIST,
            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE,
            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.REMOVE,
            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.REFRESH,
            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    private List<Investment> investment;

    @ManyToMany(
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST},
            targetEntity = Discount.class,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "cupons_campanha_pedido")
    private List<Discount> discountList;

    @Column(name = "nfeAccessKey")
    private String nfeAccessKey;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @Cascade(value = {org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
    @JoinColumn(name = "idOrder")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Item> itens;
```

I got a lot of *object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.company.entity.Investment*

For me was very strange setting as CascadeType.ALL and setting again all the possibles enumeration.  So I change just investment annotations:

```
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", targetEntity = Investment.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
        private List<Investment> investment;
```

The first exception stopped. But right know I got this (isn't common but happens):

> WARN - 2019-01-31 19:25:18.470: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23503 ERROR -
>   2019-01-31 19:25:18.471: Batch entry 0 delete from order where
>   id=1096523 was aborted: ERROR: update or delete on table "order"
>   violates foreign key constraint "fk10e0b022beb033fc" on table
>   "orderinvestment"   Detail: Key (id)=(1096523) is still referenced
>   from table "orderinvestment".  Call getNextException to see other
>   errors in the batch. WARN - 2019-01-31 19:25:18.471: SQL Error: 0,
>   SQLState: 23503 ERROR - 2019-01-31 19:25:18.472: ERROR: update or
>   delete on table "order" violates foreign key constraint
>   "fk10e0b022beb033fc" on table "orderinvestment"   Detail: Key
>   (id)=(1096523) is still referenced from table "orderinvestment".
>   ERROR - 2019-01-31 19:25:18.472: Could not synchronize database state
>   with session org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException:
>   Could not execute JDBC batch update   at
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)

This happens when calls

```
getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(entity);
```

I know that Hibernate is a JPA implementation but there are some issues using JPA annotations. So it's better using just Hibernate annotations. In this case, **Investment is set as org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL. Why this is happening?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to synchronize both sides of the relationship:

```
parent.getChildren().remove(child); // on the parent side
child.getParent() = null; // on the child side
```

The other solution would be to remove orphans: `removeOrphans = true` at `@OneToMany` annotation. This can be also done on database level.

Answer (score 0):

Delete operation is not cascaded because @OneToMany [cascade option is be default none](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#cascade()). Try to set @OneToMany(cascade=ALL)

Hibernate is implementation of JPA. JPA anotations can be used without Hibernate anotations, but not Hibernate without JPA anotations.

Try to remove hibernate anotation @Cascade and use just JPA cascade in @OneToMany.